# If a perfectly inelastic collision occurs, but no sound is generated and no damage occurs, where does the KE go?

Tags: collision, kinetic-theory

If two objects collided and stuck together but no sound was generated and no damage occurs, by law of conservation of mechanical energy it would still lost an equal amount of energy as if it did make a loud noise or get severely damaged. (By energy lost I mean that it is converted to another form because MV + MV = MV for perfectly inelastic but ke has v squared so the system gas less total energy) so where would it go in this case?

Comment: Inelastic collision = damage

Comment: @Stéphane Your equating damage to an inelastic collision and a temperature increase (below) seems odd to me. What definition are you using for the technical term "damage"?

Comment: Well that's the question. Damage is not a physical notion. See how wikipedia describe [inelastic collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision): " In collisions of macroscopic bodies, some kinetic energy is turned into vibrational energy of the atoms, causing a heating effect, and the bodies are deformed." It is too far-stretched to consider that a deformation is a damage?

Comment: @Stéphane A bit; idealized elastic deformation causes no permanent damage. After the load is removed, the material rebounds, unchanged, and the strain energy is either converted to heat or does work on another system.

Answer (score 2):

Heat: the objects would get hot.

I don't know if people still play squash, but if you've ever played it you'll find that the balls (which, obviously are not perfectly inelastic, nor are they silent) get really quite hot as they absorb energy in collisions.

Comment: Heat counts as damage I guess...

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case of a collision where the incoming object hits a perfectly elastic spring mounted on the target object.  The spring compresses as the incoming object slows;  at the instant that the incoming object comes to a momentary stop, a latch closes to lock the two objects together.  There is no energy lost in this locking process.

The "missing" kinetic energy is stored as potential energy in the compression of the spring.  There is no heating for an ideal spring. If the latch were to fail, the collision would proceed to its elastic completion.

So, does compressing a spring constitute "damage"?